# Unserialize form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I used `serialize()` to get form values, for getting values back i split the serialized string, but the values are uri encoded, like '@' is replaced by '%40', i used `decodeURIComponent()` to decode, the issues looked like solved but still i am getting spaces replaced by '+' sign. can use `string.replace()` but it would replace my legitimate '+' signs in the string. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are legitimate `+` in the string it will already be encoded as `%2B`. So before callling `decodeURIComponent()` on the string replace all the `+` which represent the space in the string by space and then call `decodeURIComponent()` to decode the string.

Use this code

```
var str = "%4Bseri%2Balized+String+plus"
str = str.replace(/\+/g, " ");
str = decodeURIComponent(str);
alert(str);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5p9qa/)**